# load link content of left nav in different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, xhtml

I have top nav,left nav whose links are driven by top nav link being clicked and the page itself is two columns layout with left nav and content container with a top nav

```
 <div id="topnav">Topic1 | Topic 2 | Topic 3</div>

    <div id="navigation">
      <!--all links from topic1 by default, or topic 2 links if topic 2 clicked-->
        <a href="home.html">Home</a>
        <a href="pictures.html">Picture</a>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
         <!-- content will load here -->
    </div>
```

when I click on topic 1, all the links belonging to topic 1 should load in left nav and
When I click pictures, the my pictures should load in #content.
How do I do this in jquery or javascript?
please help..jquery newbie here..

Comment: You've got two problems with loading google.com on your page, one is same origin policy and the other is X-Frame-Options

Comment: i am not trying to load external site at all. they will be my own html files. I just used google.com as example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<a class="loader" href="home.html">Link 1</a>
<div id="content"></div>
```

JavaScript (using jQuery)

```
$('a.loader').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Like @Musa said, the URLs you're loading should be in your own domain.

Comment: It works fine for me. Check out the edit I made to the JavaScript and try that. Also, you're using jQuery, yes? http://jquery.com/

Comment: Can you please post your code? This should work fine for you. What browser? Did you change your example to use `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: O! Shi! I didn't use $(document).ready() ... is that causing it?

Comment: I have no issues running your code. What browser are you using?

Comment: Can you put your code in jsfiddle and send me the link please?

Comment: yeap tried in chrome and the link test.html opens in a new full window instead of inside the #main div

Comment: I tried your exact code (I just created my own local version of home.html) in Chrome and Safari and it works perfectly fine. I can't do a jsFiddle because you're trying to load another HTML page and I don't think jsFiddle will allow that. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: where did you put the home.html file? in the same folder as the index.html?

Comment: jquery reference link was not correct...it worked. Thank you for bearing with me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use frames:

index.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ca" lang="ca">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Site</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="100,*">
  <frame src="topnav.htm" name="topnav" />
  <frameset cols="300,*">
    <frame name="navigation" />
    <frame name="content" />
  </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

topnav.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Topnav</title>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="topic1.htm" target="navigation">Topic 1</a> | 
<a href="topic2.htm" target="navigation">Topic 2</a> | 
<a href="topic3.htm" target="navigation">Topic 3</a> | 
</body>
</html>
```

topic1.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Topic1</title>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="content1-1.htm" target="content">Content 1</a> | 
<a href="content1-2.htm" target="content">Content 2</a> | 
<a href="content1-3.htm" target="content">Content 3</a> | 
</body>
</html>
```

And then, create your

- content1-1.htm
- content1-2.htm
- content1-3.htm

Do the same for topic2.htm and topic3.htm

Comment: Please don't use iframes in this way.

Comment: @tptcat Is really that bad? I took the code from a page that I made some time ago, when I didn't know what w3c and its standards were (I have improved it adding doctype and other things). But it works, so I thought that it was (more or less) good.

Comment: Sure. It works and that's good, but it's just not a very clean, simple, or elegant way of solving this problem (just look at how much extra code there is in your example). And generally speaking, an `iframe` is _almost_ never the right approach.